# AndroidPlot and scrollable charts

Tags: android, androidplot

I am using AndroidPlot and am having a problem with the chart. As my data grows, I would like the chart for older data to move beyond the screen area. Users can use scroll for viewing chart for older data. Can someone help me in achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirly clear what you mean but I think looking at the [Multi-touch zoom and scroll example](http://androidplot.com/wiki/A_Simple_XYPlot_with_multi-touch_zooming_and_scrolling) will probobly help.

Comment: Broken link imperative to answer